# CSS large photos blurry only on iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, responsive, blurry

My site is coded in html & CSS, and working ok on desktop and android.

However, I have several large photos that are not working as responsive when viewed on iPhone, so they appear very blurry. My site is: [www.natalie-stuart.fr](http://www.natalie-stuart.fr)

Some images are PNG and some JPEG, so it's not to do with them being PNGs.

To see the problem you'll need to view it actually on an iPhone (if viewed in the inspector on a desktop it seems fine).

The site is responsive with media queries so that the images resize on different screens, but this is not working *only* on iPhone.

Could anyone help me with this?
Thank you in advance!